# Should gnome be producing so much syslog activity?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, syslog

```
$ cut -d' ' -f5 /var/log/syslog.1 | sed -e 's/\[.*//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
  1  colord
  1  cracklib:
  1  update-notifier.desktop
  2  avahi-daemon
  2  gsd-color
  3  dhclient
  5  PackageKit:
  6  nm-dispatcher:
  7  whoopsie
  8  snapd
 12  NetworkManager
 14  dbus-daemon
 20  gvfsd-metadata
 29  smartd
 40  gnome-shell
 53  anacron
 78  gnome-software
 78  systemd
174  CRON
725  org.gnome.Shell.desktop
```

More than two thirds of the `syslog` entries are from gnome.

For Ubuntu 18.04, is this:

- normal.
- normal, but configurable to report only the significant events.
- broken, something needs to be changed.

Comment: Well, I suggest that you read some of those log entries and decide for yourself if there is a problem.

Comment: I think it's normal. Why it shouldn't ? It is like that on every ubuntu gnome installs.

Answer (score 0):

Under 16.04 with Unity Desktop things look much different:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f5 /var/log/syslog.1 | sed -e 's/\[.*//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
      1 AptDaemon.PackageKit:
      1 AptDaemon.Trans:
      1 cracklib:
      1 lightdm
      1 org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5
      2 50-motd-news
      2 accounts-daemon
      2 alsactl
      2 colord-sane:
      2 /hpfax:
      2 loadkeys
      2 org.ayatana.bamf
      2 org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor
      2 polkitd
      2 rc.local
      2 rsyslogd-2007:
      2 rsyslogd-2039:
      2 rsyslogd-2222:
      2 speech-dispatcher
      2 systemd-sysctl
      2 ureadahead
      3 systemd-timesyncd
      3 systemd-udevd
      4 apport
      4 AptDaemon:
      4 AptDaemon.Worker:
      4 nautilus:
      4 org.a11y.atspi.Registry
      4 org.gnome.ScreenSaver
      4 systemd-fsck
      4 udisksd
      4 virtualbox
      5 org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine
      5 org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer
      6 apparmor
      6 colord
      6 cron
      6 mount
      6 org.gtk.vfs.Daemon
      6 systemd-modules-load
      7 systemd-tmpfiles
      8 resetmsmice
      8 rsyslogd:
      8 tlp
      9 org.freedesktop.FileManager1
     10 sSMTP
     10 thermald
     11 gpu-manager
     12 org.debian.apt
     13 anacron
     15 gnome-session-binary
     16 nvidia-persistenced:
     16 pulseaudio
     20 fwupd
     20 sensors
     20 snapd
     21 acpid:
     24 mtp-probe:
     32 nm-dispatcher:
     36 udev-configure-printer
     40 smartd
     41 dnsmasq
     45 eyesome
     46 systemd-sleep
     61 bluetoothd
     71 CRON
     82 dhclient
     84 dbus
     96 gnome-session
    106 rtkit-daemon
    163 upowerd
    183 avahi-daemon
    187 wpa_supplicant
    596 NetworkManager
    643 systemd
   2606 kernel:
   3988 ntfs-3g
```

On my system I get a lot of permission errors with `ntfs-3g` but I really don't care enough to spend the time to fix them. Your errors for Gnome desktop should probably be researched.